# How to implement a trait for a generic type of function pointer, no matter whose arguments types are references or not

Tags: rust

I want: for a trait, e.g. `Foo`, any `fn(T1,T2)->()` should implement it, and I don't care whether `T1` or `T2` is a reference or not.

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn hello_world(&self) -> String {
        "hello world".into()
    }
}
impl<T1, T2> Foo for fn(T1, T2) -> () {}

fn a_dummy_sample_function(_: i32, _:i32) {}

fn main() {
    let fn_ptr : fn(i32, i32)->() = a_dummy_sample_function;
    (fn_ptr).hello_world();
}
```

So far, it works well.

If I change the type of first argument to `&i32`,

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn hello_world(&self) -> String {
        "hello world".into()
    }
}
impl<T1, T2> Foo for fn(T1, T2) -> () {}

fn foo_imp(_: &i32, _:i32) {}

fn main() {
    let fn_ptr : fn(&i32, i32)->() = foo_imp;
    fn_ptr.hello_world();
}
```

Then, I've got the following compilation errors.

```
  --> src/main.rs:12:12
   |
12 |     fn_ptr.hello_world();
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `for<'r> fn(&'r i32, i32)`
   |
   = note: `fn_ptr` is a function, perhaps you wish to call it
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `Foo` defines an item `hello_world`, perhaps you need to implement it
```

I can fix the compilation error as below

```
impl<T1, T2> Foo for for<'a> fn(&'a T1, T2) -> () {}
```

But it is not what I want, I want any function pointer with any types of two arguments whether it is a reference or not.

Comment: Hmm, a bit awkward since `fn(&i32, i32)` is generic over all lifetimes that could be passed to it, but in order to call `hello_world` the compiler must pick a particular lifetime such that `T1` is a complete type.

Comment: How do you imagine this trait being used? I assume just printing "hello world" isn't your true goal. How you intend to use `Foo` affects how you would handle the references involved.

Comment: @kmdreko, I would like to explore the possibility of Rust. As a scheme/Erlang programmer,  I've got many difficulties related to high order functions in Rust. This is one of them. I realized `lifetime` + `type checking` is really a challenging task for Rust.

Comment: I think you'll find that Rust does not have the kind of flexibility that you can find in functional languages. Your difficulties probably come from Rust's poor higher-kinded type support and that lifetimes introduce a layer of genericism that the borrow checker doesn't let you ignore.

Comment: But back to your question at hand, it is important when trying to apply concepts from a different language to have a *concrete* goal that you're trying to achieve. I again ask how exactly you want to use `Foo` because `T1` can't be generic over all lifetimes if you want to use functions with a `'static` lifetime for example. Or if you're hoping to call this function with arguments derived from another object, you can constrain the types to match. It is possible that there's an easy answer, or its possible there is no answer depending on what exactly you're after.